# Latex: \tableofcontent start with an arbitrary section

Tags: latex, sections, tableofcontents

Usually when use \tableofcontent in Latex, it starts with Section 1, e.g.,

```
Contents

1 Introduction ..... 1
2 Something ........ 2
3 Conclusion ....... 4
4 blablabla ........ 6
```

Is there anything to create a table of content like this:

```
Contents

3 Conclusion ....... 4
4 blablabla ........ 6
```

That is, in this example, skipping sections 1 and 2 and only list sections 3 and 4?

LaTeX example: I want to insert the table of contents after Section 3 and before Section S-1:

```
\documentclass[pdftex, noinfoline]{imsart}

\begin{document}

\section{sec1}

\section{sec2}

\section{sec3}

\tableofcontents

\section{secS-1}

\section{secS-2}
```

Comment: this will depend on your documentclass. Please make a [mre]

Comment: Thanks! I just added an example. My Latex document class is imsart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `titletoc` package:

```
\documentclass[pdftex, noinfoline]{imsart}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\section{sec1}

\section{sec2}

\section{sec3}


\section*{Table of Contents}
\startcontents
\printcontents{ }{1}{}

\section{secS-1}

\section{secS-2}


    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Thanks to your quick response! 

But the output still not the form I expected. Is there a way to increase the space between the section number and section name? And if you know how to reduce the line spacing in the table of contents?

Comment: @Paul If you have new questions, please ask a new question